# Change join contain() condition in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, contain

I try to use contain to make an full join of 2 Tables but i don't know how to change the condition:

```
$select= $this->Friends->find('all')
                ->order(['Friends.id' => 'ASC'])
                ->contain([
                    'Animals'
                ])
                ->where(['animal1_id'=> $animalsid,
                    'confirmed'=>'1'
                ]);
            $this->set(compact('select'));
```

And so look the SQL:

```
 SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  friends Friends 
  INNER JOIN animals Animals ON Animals.id = (Friends.animal2_id) 
WHERE 
  (
    animal1_id = 4 
    AND confirmed = 1
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  Friends.id ASC
```

The problem is that this **Friends.animal2_id** i want to change with **Friends.animal1_id** but i don't know how? Maybe there another methods? I tried to use join but i get just one table not both.

Comment: "animal1_id" & "confirmed" column belongs to which table, friends or animals?

Comment: @bikash.bilz  to table friends there i have 'animal1_id' and 'animal2_id' and confirmed. When i use contain he automaticlly take the 'animal2_id' for join, but i need 'animal1_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering that you have ***belongsTo***  relationship between the two model **friends** and **animals**.

So you just have to change the foreignKey name in the association, so update the association in your **Friends** model like

```
$this->belongsTo('Animals', [
    'foreignKey' => 'animal1_id',  //Here the column name you want to use for join
    'className'=>'Animals',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

EDIT(for comment query):-
If you want to select other tables, you can achieve this in two ways

In controller

```
$this->loadModel('OtherModelName');   //This will load your model to $this object
$other_table_result = $this->OtherModelName->find('all')->toArray();
```

Method to use raw SQL queries,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: i find another method also by using joint, thx of lot for your help.

Comment: do you know maybe how to make an select*from table... If i am using join the cakephp automaticlly select jut from first table if i will make $this->Tablename->find('all')...?

Comment: @Christian Yes is the alternative way to solve your issue to use join in the find.

Comment: @Christian I'm not sure what you want to achieve, still Using ORM saves your time, so It's good to use ORM rather than using raw queries. I am adding some code to help you